# how to explain different display of SVG between Blazor and pain HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am new to web development and I have been facing an issue with SVG rendering. I have the same code in Blazor and in plain HTML/CSS that render differently in the same browser. Here below I present a minimal example reproducing the error. I would be very grateful if someone can tell me if it is a Blazor bug or if it is me doing something incorrect

- The plain HTML/CSS is here (the CSS being completly identic as the one above)

```css
.square,
.select-all-button {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin-right: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.square {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="square ">1</div>
    <div class="square ">2</div>
    <div class="square ">3</div>
    <div class="square ">4</div>
    <div class="square ">5</div>

    <div class="select-all-button">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M20.496 5.627A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 22 7.75v10A4.25 4.25 0 0 1 17.75 22h-10a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-2.123-1.504l2.097.004H17.75a2.75 2.75 0 0 0 2.75-2.75v-10l-.004-.051V5.627ZM17.246 2a2.25 2.25 0 0 1 2.25 2.25v12.997a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-2.25 2.25H4.25A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 2 17.247V4.25A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 4.25 2h12.997ZM13.47 7.47l-3.89 3.888-.98-1.308a.75.75 0 1 0-1.2.9l1.5 2a.75.75 0 0 0 1.13.08l4.5-4.5a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06-1.06Z" fill="#212121"/>
        </svg>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

- The corresponding Blazor is here

```blazor
<div class="row">
    @for (var i = 1; i < 7; i++)
    {
        <div class="square"> @i </div>
    }

        <div class="select-all-button">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <path d="M20.496 5.627A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 22 7.75v10A4.25 4.25 0 0 1 17.75 22h-10a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-2.123-1.504l2.097.004H17.75a2.75 2.75 0 0 0 2.75-2.75v-10l-.004-.051V5.627ZM17.246 2a2.25 2.25 0 0 1 2.25 2.25v12.997a2.25 2.25 0 0 1-2.25 2.25H4.25A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 2 17.247V4.25A2.25 2.25 0 0 1 4.25 2h12.997ZM13.47 7.47l-3.89 3.888-.98-1.308a.75.75 0 1 0-1.2.9l1.5 2a.75.75 0 0 0 1.13.08l4.5-4.5a.75.75 0 0 0-1.06-1.06Z" fill="#212121"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
</div>
```

The 2 piece of codes produce respectively:

[image]

Hence, HTML/CSS code tend to respect the dimension requested for the SVG but Blazor does not.

Again thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:  Looking in Edge Dev Tools, I noticed the following which might help to find what is going on.

1. Bazor Code:
   [image]
   [image]
2. HTML/CSS

[image]
[image]

Comment: There must be some additional wrapping CSS in the Blazor output. Can you confirm? Do you have a link to share?

Comment: @CharlieSchliesser I actually never looked at the output file, I am either looking at the result in browser for  Debug or directly at the published site through Azure pipeline. To answer your question, while debuging I looked at the CSS in Edge DevTool and I can confirm it is exactly as the one above. If it is what I was supposed to look for, let me know and I will edit my question and put that extra piece of information.

Comment: Reset your css. Kevin Powell has some good videos on this on YouTube. Blazor does not perform magic in the HTML, it will be a css library doing this or a css file in your code.

Comment: Indeed, I realized there might be some CSS conflict somewhere. I will dig into it and will surely update the question.

Comment: IF you have the same CSS in BOTH, first why NOT? And second if so what differs in the rendered HTML?  IF you have style IN elements, move it to the CSS where it belongs.

Comment: I have often seen where someone puts element level CSS in then does stuff later to override it and it all starts to become a HUGE set of CSS.  Example: `a { something...}  div a { something... !important; }`

Comment: don't do this where it is: `margin-right: 10px;` try to do `row-gap: 0.625em;` as 10/16 = 0.625 and 16px is most browsers default.